# IT-сфера, Python

Tags: python, typedef

Что такое декоратор в программировании?
Например, интересует меня на языке Python)

Answer (score 1):

Декоратор это функция, которая принимает функцию и возвращает новую функцию.

Принятая функция как-то обрабатывается или при вызове декоратора или при вызове возвращаемой функции замыканием.

Пример

```
def logthis(fu):
    def inner(*a,**k):
        ret = fu(*a,**k)
        print(f'{fu} called')
        return ret
    return inner
```

Answer (score 1):

Декораторы в Python - это способ создать обертку вокруг интересующей нас функции. В общем виде я бы описал декораторы в виде такой конструкции:

```py
def decorator(func):

    def to_decorate():
        print("действия до исполнения")
        
        func()

        print("действия после исполнения")

    return to_decorate
```

Таким образом, мы задаем функцию, которая делает какие-то действия до исполнения и после исполнения предполагаемой функции. Теперь можно использовать эту конструкцию на живом примере:

```py
@decorator
def main():
    print("Я - главное действие")
```

Декорируя функции на стадии их инициализации (создания\описания) мы можем задать им некоторую оберточную среду. Результатом исполнения функции main() с нашим декоратором @decorate станет следующий вывод в консоль:

```
действия до исполнения
Я - главное действие
действия после исполнения
```

Некоторые мои знакомые называют эту штуку "микро-мидлвари".
Вообще, зная логику работы Python, с декораторами можно творить и более интересные вещи.